# How to fix "fatal error: x.264 no such file or directory"

Tags: c, makefile, x264, libx264

I wrote a makefile which builds a C program attaching the x.264 header. After trying to execute the makefile in terminal I receive the fatal error:
"example.c line [line of #include ] x264.h no such file or directory". Below you can find the C code and makefile (located in the same folder, the library - containing the x264.pc file- is in the folder libx264 of the parent folder). I would be very grateful if you could help with the linkage.

Makefile:

```
    CC = gcc

    CFLAGS = -c -Wall `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=../libx264 && pkg-config            --cflags x264`
    LDFLAGS = -static `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=../libx264 && pkg-config --libs --static libx264`


    all: Release

    Debug: CFLAGS += -g
    Debug: example

    Release: example

    test: example.o
        $(CC) -o example example.o $(LDFLAGS)

    test.o: example.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) example.c -o example.o

    clean:
        rm -f example.o example
```

example.c code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <x264.h>
    int main( int argc, char **argv )
    {
        int width, height;
         return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Install `libx264-dev` in Ubuntu or Debian.

Comment: Hi. The task or challange is to get the makefile working. Bat thaank you, in case I don't manage it I will install the library.

Comment: The makefile works just fine. It's the fact that you don't have the header files for the library installed.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to tell the compiler (to be more precise: the preprocessor) where the header file is using the `-I` option:

```
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -I../libx264
```

If I'm right, you need to unpack that `.pc` file, so that `x264.h` is indeed in `../libx264`.

Similar thing for the linker flags (assuming there's a `libx264.a` file in `../libx264`), where you have to specify where the library is using the `-L` option:

```
LDFLAGS = -static -L../libx264 -lx264
```

Alternatively you could of course also write:

```
LDFLAGS = -static ../libx264/libx264.a
```

Comment: Thank you! 
There was one error: the a package was libx264.a not x.264.a. Adding the -I `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH= -I ../libx264 && pkg-config --cflags x264` is not working. I get the error: /bin/sh: 1 export: -I : bad variable name. If I delete the -I I get the same error for the next word: /bin/sh: 1 export: ../libx264 : bad variable name. What is sure is that the parent folder contains the libx264 and the example folders. The libx264 contans a lot of files including: x264.c, x264.h, x265.pc and libx264.a. The example folder contains the example.c file and the makefile which does not work.

Comment: That needs to be included in the Makefile. RTFM for more details.